# Make a difference between a tab event and a flick event on listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a listbox which contains a list of images; I don't know how to differentiate betwwen a   Flick event and a Tap event, to make a zoom on the chosen image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is additional support for detecting touch in the XNA library. Trying adding the  Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch reference to your project

Include the following using statement:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
```

Subscribe to the required events in your constructor as follows:

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap | GestureType.Flick;
```

On your list box create an event for Manipulation Completed as follows:

```
ManipulationCompleted="ListBoxDays_ManipulationCompleted"
```

You could add code to the that event method to track the type of events that have been completed with the following code:

```
private void ListBoxDays_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

        if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Tap)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Flick)
        {
            //Do something else
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Tap` event on all elements (in Mango). `Tap` event don't raised when user scrolls a list.

Also, you can place an image inside a retemplated `Button` (leave only content holder). Then you get for free `Click event` and `Tilt Effect` as well